# ordered held -- meaning

Tags: ellipsis, participles

Example with a context (Yahoo news article ["Families of Charleston 9 forgive shooting suspect in court"](http://news.yahoo.com/gunman-feared-blacks-were-taking-over-world-081618717.html#)):

> Roof, who faces nine counts of murder, was **ordered held** on $1 million bond on a separate gun charge.

I'm not really following that grammatically.

Comment: "He was ordered *to be* held..."

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's a typographical error?

Comment: No error.  "Held" here is a participle used like an adjective.  Similar to "It appeared *assembled*" or "They feel *justified*".

Comment: Some similar patterns: *get it finished, make it known, have someone killed, want something done.* This one is *The court ordered him held.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here "was ordered held" means he is being *detained*. It is not a typographical error. Full form would be "was ordered to be held" as user3169 suggested. Here is a search from Google regarding ["was ordered held"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20ordered%20held%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&gws_rd=ssl). You can search those pages to get some more examples.

**[hold](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hold)**:

> *[with object]* Keep or detain (someone):

Answer (score 0):

Here, the word *ordered* refers to ordered by a court, or ordered by a judge. For example, if I was arrested for littering, I might say:

> The judge ordered me to pay a $50 fine.

In this case, the suspect (who happens to have the last name of "Roof") was not ordered to pay a fine, but he was ordered to be put into jail until someone could make a $1 million bond payment assuring that he will show up for his trial later. Newspapers will often use the phrase "held on bond" to mean that someone is being kept in jail until someone arranges for a bond payment to be made. The bond process is depicted in this image:

[image]